# How I can parse a GET response from facebook using node.js

Tags: facebook, node.js

How I can parse a GET response from facebook using node.js here is my code:

```
var options = {
  host: 'graph.facebook.com',
  path: 'url',
  key: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-cert.pem'),
  agent: false
};
var fb = https.get(options, function(res) {
console.log("statusCode: ", res);

  res.on('data', function(d) {
   console.log(d);

  });

}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.error(e);
});
```

Instead of printing the data I'd expect, it's printing some buffer value.

Comment: its printing response. If you need string and not buffer, use console.log(d.toString()). If you need complete response body, concatenate it with previous value.

Answer (score 1):

Try explicitly setting the encoding in order to receive human-readable data:

`var fb = https.get(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    ....`